# imprimir todos los resultados de localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Ahora mismo tengo dos documentos, uno en el que obtengo datos de un formulario y otro donde los imprimo. Los paso de uno a otro con `localStorage`:

Este es el HTML del formulario

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>023 : form DataTable</title>
    <script src="js/023.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formBuscar" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="txt">
    <input type="date" class="din">
    <input type="date" class="dfn">
</form>
<button type="button">Busca ya</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let frm = document.querySelector('form');
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        getInpts(frm);
    });
});

function getInpts(frm){
    frm.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(item=>{
        localStorage.setItem('length', frm.length);
        if(item.value){
            for(i=0;i<frm.length;i++){
                localStorage.setItem('value'+i, item.value);
            }
            window.location.assign('http://localhost/pruebas/021.html');
        }
    });
}
```

Como se puede ver, guardo 4 valores distintos en localStorage, los 3 input y el length del formulario, es decir, cuantos input haya.

En dicho punto, si sustituyo el `window.location.assign` por un `console.log` del localStorage, obtengo los 3 resultados que quiero (dentro del bucle for, claro).

Aquí muestro cómo recojo los datos:

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let lng = localStorage.getItem('length');
    for(i=0;i<lng;i++){
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('value'+i));
    }
})
```

Pero sólo me muestra el último dato, y juraría que lo estoy guardando en objetos distintos.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Sería más fácil crear un arreglo (u objeto) con pares `campo: valor`, guardar con `JSON.stringify()` y leerlo con `JSON.parse()`, con eso evitas tener una variable por cada campo y el mantenimiento es mucho más sencillo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función getinpts tiene un doble bucle innecesario que machaca los datos guardados. Debería ser algo como:

```
function saveInputs(form){
  const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
    if(input.value){
      localStorage.setItem('value' + index, input.value);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem('length', inputs.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya tengo la solución, al menos, algo que me ha servido. Si hay algo mejor que mi solución por favor, decídmelo:

Tuve que cambiar el bucle for donde meto los valores del formulario en localStorage, ya que lo que estaba haciendo es meter 3 veces el primer valor, por la iteración del forEach y después del for, 3 veces el segundo y 3 veces el tercero.

Con haberle agregado desde un principio un index al forEach, hubiera bastado:

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let frm = document.querySelector('form');
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        getInpts(frm);
    });
});

function getInpts(frm){
    frm.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((item,index)=>{
        localStorage.setItem('length', frm.length);
        if(item.value){
            localStorage.setItem('value'+index, item.value);
            window.location.assign('http://localhost/pruebas/021.html');
        }
    });
}
```

y recoger los datos tal y como lo tenía:

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let lng = localStorage.getItem('length');
    for(i=0;i<lng;i++){
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('value'+i));
    }
})
```

Comment: Sigues guardado N veces el número de inputs